# Form suddenly stopped inserting data - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, html

I have a php form that was working fine and has just stopped working abruptly. I can't seem to figure out where the issue is. It's not throwing any particular error, it just refreshes the page on submit and clears out the data that was entered into the form. Nothing is getting inserted into the database. Any ideas on where there may be an issue here? Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: I've stripped down the code and it's not displaying any errors on submission. It just resets the form as if nothing happened. It is connecting to the database because it will display any fields with data available. I'm going nuts trying to figure this out. I don't understand why it's not working and I can't seem to get any meaningful error data.

```
<?php
session_start();

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {
header('location:index.php');
}
else{

if(isset($_GET['edit']))
    {
        $editid=$_GET['edit'];
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="../images/";
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $website=$_POST['website'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $zip=$_POST['zip'];
    $idedit=$_POST['idedit'];
    $image=$_POST['image'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $image=$final_file;
        }

    $sql="UPDATE users SET name=(:name), email=(:email), category=(:category), mobile=(:mobileno), description=(:description), website=(:website), address=(:address), city=(:city), state=(:state), zip=(:zip), image=(:image) WHERE id=(:idedit)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':mobileno', $mobileno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':website', $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':state', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':zip', $zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':idedit', $idedit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $msg="Information Updated Successfully";
  }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Edit</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * from users where id = :editid";
        $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':editid',$editid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $cnt=1;
?>
    <h3 class="page-title">Edit Marker : <?php echo htmlentities($result->name); ?></h3>

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imgform">

<img class="profileimage" src="../images/<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>" >
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
        <input type="hidden" name="image" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->mobile);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->website);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->address);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->city);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
    <select name="state" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->zip);?>">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
    <textarea style="height:100px" wrap="soft" name="description" class="form-control" ><?php echo htmlentities($result->description);?></textarea>

    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="idedit" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>" >


    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">SAVE CHANGES</button>

</form>


</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please do not just dump a file for us to eyeball-debug. What does the error log say or the console?

Comment: PS: NEVER call anything "submit" in a form. Change the name if you EVER want to programmatically submit it

Comment: @mplungjan I have researched this extensively, That's why I'm asking for help. This form was working perfectly and then stopped. This isn't just a minimal reproducible example, it's functional code as of a couple of days ago. I respect the community's time and expertise, which is why I included all of the code AFTER researching extensively.

Comment: So you need to call the php on its own and see the php errors - use a simple form and echo all errors etc

Comment: @mplungjan I've stripped down the code to just the basics and updated it above. I added PHP error reporting. I triggered a couple of page errors to test it and that's working, but there are no errors on submit. It's still just resetting the page on submit.